# Disable git hook in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

We use git for our code base via visual studio and via cygwin. We created git hooks that work in cygwin bash like

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-checkout
#! /bin/bash
GV=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

Obviously this does not work in visual studio, and e.g. after checkout in visual studio we get the error message

```
Open repositorys:
C:\temt\repo
Error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/post-checkout: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to disable ( or use a different set of .. ) git hooks in visual studio? Or can we prepend an early exit that is only executed in a DOS shell? Or can we call cygwin bash for the git hook execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `sh` shell instead of `bash` like:

```
#! /bin/sh
...
```

Comment: @Heiner, no not really. Was kind of trial and error. Seems Visual Studio only understands sh shell and not bash shell